# Methods for BVP and PDE

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I am learning numerical analysis, and recently I learnt several methods for solving BVPs and PDEs. However, the examples in the textbook is very vague and it uses Matlab code to find the answer. I am wondering if there exist some formulas that we can apply to solve problems by hand for the following methods:

1. shooting method
2. collocation
3. Finite element method
4. Forward finite difference method (parabolic equations of the heat equation)
5. Backward finite difference method (parabolic equations of the heat equation)
6. Crank Nicolson method

It would be nice if you can provide websites with examples. I am very confused now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We will not be tested on coding during the final exam, so I think we will be tested on the formulas. And I found them unclear in the textbook. Thanks!